# Record Not Being Deleted In Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hello i am having a weird issue that i do not understand, i am trying to delete a record in **laravel**. This is my **destroy** method in my resource controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $ins = Institution::find($id);
    $success = $ins->delete();

    return [
        'success' => $success
    ];
}
```

This is the **model**:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class Institution extends Model {

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $table = 'sys_institutions';

}
```

Now **success** always **returns true** indicating that the record indeed has been deleted but when i check my db this is not the case.

I have tried returning **$ins** after the delete as well, the column **deleted_at** seems to have a date but this is not saved to the database.  In my database table **deleted_at** is always ***NULL***.

Now i did not create my tables with **migrations** i dunno if that might have something to do with my current problem.

I have checked the **$id** and it is indeed correct.

I have also tried using:

```
$success = Institution::destroy($id);
```

That didn't work either.

Comment: Soft deletion will leave the row in the table with `deleted_at` being updated. Have you tried `->forceDelete()` to remove it entirely?

Comment: Nope but i did say the "deleted_at" column in my database was not being updated, it is always NULL.

Comment: If you didn't write it via the migration, that may be the reason.  What data type and size (if not datetime) did you set for the `deleted_at` column?

Comment: i used TIMESTAMP not DATETIME, is that wrong?

Comment: Found the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27084644/laravel-eloquent-orm-update-and-delete-not-working